# Android fragment thread

Tags: android, flash

I know every UI is normaly on Ui thread but i have discovered fragment so i have split my app in two fragment one bottom who launche a web view and a swf. and one in the rest of the screen who do the same but with an other swf...

Probleme is this flash make my double core tablet ram like hell... So with the fragment can we make 2 Ui thread one per fragment or not?

any other way to make it faster? Any cheat to use double thread for draw i mean video game use it right? because if all game lag every time we have 2 flash we can't play a lot of game..

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend this but if you want to create another thread to handle UI events you must create a [looper thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html). One thing to keep in mind is that you can only modify views from the thread they were created on. So if you create one fragment on this looper thread you must interact with it on the looper thread to mess with the views.

Comment: no interact include broadcast or not? i need to launch some intent with extra to update the flash content...